# Space with hypercomponents whose restriction to a hypercomponent is not locally finite

Tags: gn.general-topology

#### Problem

Give an example of a topological space $(X, \mathcal{T})$ for whose [hyperconnected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperconnected_space) (aka [irreducible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_component)) components $\mathcal{C} \subset \mathcal{P}(X)$ it holds that $\mathcal{C}|D$ is *not* $(\mathcal{T}|D)$-locally finite for some $D \in \mathcal{C}$. Here $\mathcal{T}|D$ denotes the subspace topology on $D$, and $\mathcal{C}|D = \{C \cap D : C \in \mathcal{C}\}$ is the restriction of a cover to $D$.

#### Background

- The [excluded point topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Excluded_point_topology) on an infinite set $X$ and point $p \in X$ provides an [example](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4611804/51161) where hypercomponents are not $\mathcal{T}$-locally finite. However, in that example $\mathcal{C}|D = \{\{p\}\}$ for any $D \in \mathcal{D}$, which is $(\mathcal{T}|D)$-locally finite, and so is not a valid example for the current problem.
- Hypercomponents may intersect, and there may be infinity of them, as shown in the above example.
- Hypercomponents are closed.
- An [algebraic set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_variety) has a finite number of hypercomponents (under the Zariski topology), so do not provide an example.
- Ultimately, I'm trying to solve [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4707631/51161) related question. Showing that there is no such space as in the current problem would resolve that question. Providing an example of such a space would provide some intuition for that question.

I [previously asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4712095/51161) this same question at Math Stackexchange, with no answers.